# Shift left and cast with float in C

Tags: c, casting

The compiler display an error when it compiles this line :

```
float Data;
unsigned long Valeur;
Data = - (1 << 2 - (Float_t)Valeur) * 2.135;
```

This is the message:

```
error: illegal type(s): int '<<' float
```

I did not find the error? Can you help me?

Comment: The compiler has told you exactly what's wrong. You can't shift by a number of bits that is not an integer. I'm not sure why the cast is in there to begin with.

Comment: maybe you should take (1<<2) into brackets, because, it doesn't make sense to shift for the float value.

Comment: @chris None of this matters. `Valeur` is not initialized, Undefined Behaviour ensues.

Comment: @Quentin, Once it compiles at least.

Comment: What a compiler would do of a non-integer bit shift would be fun to watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
- (1 << 2 - (Float_t)Valeur) * 2.135;
```

is interpreted as

```
- (1 << (2 - (Float_t)Valeur)) * 2.135;
```

and the type of `2 - (Float_t)Valeur)` is `Float_t`, which I assume is `float` or similar. You cannot shift by a floating point number.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the non-standard `Float_t` is `typedef`'d to `float` or equivalent, this:

```
Data = - (1 << 2 - (Float_t)Valeur) * 2.135;
                       ^
                       |
                      bad!
```

Is the problem. The above computes `2 - (Float_t) Valeur`, then uses the (floating-point!) result to shift. Perhaps you meant

```
Data = -((1 << 2) - (Float_t) Valeur) * 2.135;
```

or something. It's hard to be sure, it's quite strange code.

Comment: Yes it is non-standard. It is used as typedef float Float_t

Answer (score 2):

`Valeur` is used uninitialized and `<<` has lower precedence than `-`, maybe you are looking for:

```
Data = - ((1 << 2) - (Float_t)Valeur) * 2.135;
```